# Binding Vue.js. Binding in vue. Problem updating value in field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, binding, vuetify.js, vuex

There is a form in which we set the country field using `<Autocomplete>`

```
<div class="col-4 pa-0 relative">
        <Autocomplete
           v-model="new_queue.country_id"
           :items="countries"
           text="Country"
           :rules="[rules.required]"
           :readonly="readonlyField"
        />
     </div>
```

in the same form there is a table component with data in which the value of this field is displayed; `.sync` is used for communication

```
<div class="col-12 pa-0 mb-4">
   <ListVehiclesTable
      ref="ListVehiclesTable"
      :new-queue.sync="new_queue"
      @editQueuecar="editQueuecar"
      @deleteQueuecar="deleteQueuecar"
      :get-status="getStatus"
    />
</div>
```

when changing the country with the selector, everything is okay, but if you erase the field, click to the side and then select the country again, it is no longer updated in the table, what could be the problem?

Comment: Impossible to say not knowing how `new_queue` is actually used or what's going on inside these components.  Please review how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question with the relevant details.